# Additional fields on polymorphic many to many table map to Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to create a ploymorphic many-to-many relationship that also includes an additional relationship.  I can't seem to figure out how to get Eloquent to map the additional field to a model.

I have projects, users on those projects, and project roles that dictate permissions for that user on the project.

My tables:

```
Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('possessor_id');
    $table->string('possessor_type');
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('username');
});

Schema::create('project_accessors', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
    $table->integer('project_role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('project_role_id')->references('id')->on('project_roles');
    $table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('entity_type');
 });

Schema::create('project_roles', function(Blueprint $table){
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('permissions');
   $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

I define projects on users like this:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Project', 'entity', 'project_accessors')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('project_role_id');
}
```

I define users and roles on projects like this:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProjectRole');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'entity', 'project_accessors')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('project_role_id');
}
```

Is there a way to map `project_role_id` to an actual instance of my Project Role model?